# Configuration to add mdl-ext npm package to Phoenix via brunch

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch

Brunch / npm and phoenix confuses the hell out of me.  The paucity of concrete examples doesn't help.  Maybe this question can shed a little light?
Here's my config at the mo'

```
npm: {
 enabled: true,
 styles: {
   'material-design-lite': ['dist/material.min.css'],
   'mdl-ext': ['lib/mdl-ext.css']
 },
 globals: {
   material: 'material-design-lite'
 }
}
```

Couple of questions.  Whilst the mdl styles are working I'm not sure if the .js is being pulled through.  How could I check?

mdl-ext css is getting pulled through but again not sure about the js.  Also not sure how I would check.  All feels a bit secret sauce.

Answer (score 0):

Learnt some more about brunch and found the solution.

> the default brunch-configuraton.js configuration comes with this
>   "joinTo: "js/app.js" uncommented by default. So, it does not contain
>   any regex to include the js files, and by consequence it includes all
>   of them

I just needed these 2 lines in my app.js file:

```
  import 'material-design-lite/material';
  import 'mdl-ext';
```

Things become a little trickier when bundling into multiple files e.g app.js and vendor.js.  I'm still experimenting with that.

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1495
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1813